# it is routable with same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I create a mvc3 application then I add a new tab in the Home Controller called Message (in the _Layout.cshtml of the shared folder), I include the following function into the HomeController.cs

```
public string Message(string msg)
{
    return "This is my message :" + msg + " to you";
}
```

I then can route with any of the following urls

```
> http://localhost:2554/Home/Message/message=some%20message
> http://localhost:2554/Home/Message
> http://localhost:2554/Home/Message/message
```

But I don't see the msg in the display. Why three of them results in the same view ? What should I add to make msg viewable then ?

Comment: have you tried `http://localhost:2554/Home/Message?msg=some%20message` ?

Answer (score 1):

add a route in your routetable if you want it to work via the methods you were showing above

`_routeCollection.MapRoute("Message", "Home/Message/{msg}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Message", msg = ""});`